# decimal numbers, significant digits

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I am quite sure this must have been discussed many times. I am still going to ask as I have not found any useful discussion.

The question is simple, is there a way to force `LibreOffice Calc` to preserve the numbers exactly as they are entered. When one enters `1.0` `calc` saves it as `1`. This is obviously wrong. The two numbers are completely different, `1.2` is not the same as `1.20` etc. I know, one can use formatting for proper display but again. Your enter something correctly, `calc` saves it wrongly and then you use formatting to correct for that. But the whole point is that there is an unrecoverable loss of information due to this feature. Since the number is internally saved wrongly, there is no way to recover the information other than saving the number twice, once saving the number and then entering a necessary correction so that full information can be later recovered (you can think of the second piece of information that you have to enter as that formatting).

So is there some miscellaneous settings that can override this default silly behaviour?

Comment: 1.2 is the identical number to 1.20; they're just presented differently to the user. Your question is about presentation (display). There is no *unrecoverable loss of information* when you display 1.20 as 1.2 - you simply see a different presentation. There is nothing *lost*. If you don't understand, multiply 1.2 * 10 and 1.20 * 10 - is there a difference in the results? No, there isn't. They both end up as 12, whether it's displayed as 12 or 12.0 or 12.00. You're wanting them *displayed* as entered, which is what formatting accomplishes.

Comment: @KenWhite Your are not correct. The `1.2` is simply not the same as `1.20`, please read about significant digits and other related topics. The ending zero carries important information.

Comment: I am correct. There is zero loss between 1.2 and 1.20 (yes, the pun was intentional). There would be a difference if the original number was 1.3333333333333333 and it was represented as 1.3, but that's not the case with 1.2 and 1.20. There are many articles available about how floating point math works. Your examples are not affected by the display representation, and there is no *loss* with the samples you've selected. And *display* does not affect the underlying accuracy; you can choose to display 1.33333 (via formatting) as 1.3, but the actual value that would be used in math ops is 1.33333

Comment: @KenWhite Again, read at least basics on the topic of significant figures. I you say that you measured `1` liter, it says something about your measurement precision was only to `1` significant figure (so maybe it was `1.2` or `0.6` nobody knows, while if you say that you measured `1.000` liters, that says that your precision was several orders better because now you have 4 significant figures, that means it might have been (`1.0001` or `1.0004` but surely not `1.3`). So no, you are quite wrong, `1.2` and `1.20` have different meaning and are not the same numbers.

Comment: @KenWhite If you want to get into internal representation of numbers and floating point arithmetic in computers that is a different issue and based on what you are writing you do not seem to understand that very well (you should at least know how a floating point number is represented in 8 bit or 16 bit precision if you want to argument with floating point arithmetic).

Comment: Yes, I know how it's represented, and yes, I understand how it works. *You* don't seem to understand that when a spreadsheet **displays** a value, it does **not** change the *underlying value* of that number. **Display != Value**. I'm not debating floating point math; I'm debating your claim that putting 1.20 into a spreadsheet cell as a numeric value that is then displayed as 1.2 changes the actual numeric value and causes loss of precision. DIsplaying a number in a certain format does not affect the value, just the on-screen representation..

Comment: "If you say that you measured 1 liter, it says something about your measurement precision": No, in scientific sense it says **exactly** 1 liter. The measurement precision would must be mentioned additional when necessary. It **may** be that somewhere is agreed that the count of **displayed** decimal places indicates the measurement precision. So "1.2 and 1.20 have different meaning and are not the same numbers": No, 1.2 and 1.20 **may** have different meaning in sense of indicating the measurement precision. But in mathematically sense 1.2 and 1.20 are **exactly** the same numbers.

Answer (score 2):

**First to the discussion whether storing only the mathematically values of decimal numbers but not the inputted count of decimal places if they are 0 and so not required for the mathematically value may be losing information:**

Yes, that may be the case if somewhere is agreed that the count of displayed decimal places indicates the measurement precision. If this is the case, then 1.2 and 1.20 and 1.200 have different meanings. But in a pure mathematically sense 1.2 and 1.20 and 1.200 are exactly the same values.

**Now to `Calc`:**

It stores the mathematically values of numbers. This is because it does not know something about any agreement that the count of displayed decimal places indicates the measurement precision.

**Thoughts about how to respect that agreement in `Calc`:**

One could try programming a `Listener` which watches the input of the numbers in `Calc` cells and then formatting the cell dependent on the count of inputted decimal places using different number formats. Example: If inputted `1.2`, then use number format `0.0`, if inputted `1.20`, then use number format `0.00`, if inputted `1.200`, then use number format `0.000` and so on. There is [XModifyBroadcaster](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/util/XModifyBroadcaster.html) which is supported by `::com::sun::star::sheet::SheetCell`.  But the [XModifyListener.modified](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/util/XModifyListener.html) is called to late. If it is called then the value has changed already to 1.2 if 1.2000 was inputted. So this is dead end, at lest for me. Maybe someone can find a possibility listening the keyboard events while inputting into the cell before `modified` is called.

A only possible "solution" I can think of would be that cells which shall fulfilling the agreement that the count of displayed decimal places indicates the measurement precision will be formatted using number format `Text` = `@`. Cells which are formatted as such takes all inputs as text. So if inputted `1.2000` the cell stores this as text "1.2000" instead of the number 1.2. But of course then one must take in mind that the stored values are text if calculations with those values will be necessary later.